# Поднять блок вверх

Tags: css

Здравствуйте!
Хочу поднять блок с картинками выше, но когда задаю слишком большой margin-top то второй ряд просто начинает наезжать сверху на первый и съезжается в один ряд. Мне необходимо поднять одинаково 2 ряда вверх...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Страница

```js
<?php 
   define('myeshop', true);
   include("include/db_connect.php");
   include("functions/functions.php");
   session_start();
   include("include/auth_cookie.php");
  
   $id = clear_string($_GET["id"]); 

     $seoquery = mysql_query("SELECT seo_words,seo_description FROM table_products WHERE products_id='$id' AND visible='1'",$link);
     
     If (mysql_num_rows($seoquery) > 0)
     {
        $resquery = mysql_fetch_array($seoquery);
     }   
   
  If ($id != $_SESSION['countid'])
{
$querycount = mysql_query("SELECT count FROM table_products WHERE products_id='$id'",$link);
$resultcount = mysql_fetch_array($querycount); 

$newcount = $resultcount["count"] + 1;

$update = mysql_query ("UPDATE table_products SET count='$newcount' WHERE products_id='$id'",$link);  
}

$_SESSION['countid'] = $id; 
      
?>

<div class="page-container" id="PageContainer">
<main class="main-content" id="MainContent" role="main">
<?php
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE products_id='$id' AND visible='1'",$link);
If (mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0)
{
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
do
{   
if  (strlen($row1["image"]) > 0 && file_exists("./uploads_images/".$row1["image"]))
{
$img_path = './uploads_images/'.$row1["image"];
$max_width = 300; 
$max_height = 300; 
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_path); 
$ratioh = $max_height/$height; 
$ratiow = $max_width/$width; 
$ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow); 

$width = intval($ratio*$width); 
$height = intval($ratio*$height);    
}else
{
$img_path = "/images/no-image.png";
$width = 110;
$height = 200;
}     




echo  '



<div id="shopify-section-product-template" class="shopify-section"><div class="product-template__container page-width" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="ProductSection-product-template" data-section-id="product-template" data-section-type="product" data-enable-history-state="true">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="OSS Charloween Tee Black">
  <meta itemprop="url" content="https://onsomeshit.com/products/oss-charloween-tee-black">
  <meta itemprop="image" content="//styleshop.net.ua/images/future_tee_195x195@2x.jpg?v=1509391637">

  <div class="grid product-single">
    <div class="grid__item product-single__photos medium-up--one-half"><div id="FeaturedImageZoom-product-template" class="product-single__photo product-single__photo--has-thumbnails" data-zoom="//styleshop.net.ua/images/future_tee_195x195@2x.jpg?v=1509391637">
        <img src="'.$img_path.'" alt="OSS Charloween Tee Black" id="FeaturedImage-product-template" class="product-featured-img js-zoom-enabled">
      </div></div>

   
    <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half">
      <div style="margin-top: -50px;" class="site-header__menu product-single__meta">

        <h1 itemprop="name" class="product-single__title">'.$row1["title"].'</h1>

        

        <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
          <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">

          <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">

          <p class="product-single__price product-single__price-product-template">
            
              <span class="visually-hidden">Regular price</span>
              <s id="ComparePrice-product-template" class="hide"></s>
              <span class="product-price__price product-price__price-product-template">
                <span id="ProductPrice-product-template"
                  itemprop="price" content="30.0">
                  '.group_numerals($row1["price"]).' грн
                </span>
                <span class="product-price__sale-label product-price__sale-label-product-template hide">Sale</span>
              </span>
            
          </p>
          <div class="">
          <p>Описание товара</p>
    Просто лучший свитшот!</div>
          <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="product-form product-form-product-template" data-section="product-template">
            
              
                <div class="selector-wrapper js product-form__item">
                  <label for="SingleOptionSelector-0">
                    <br>Размер
                  </label>
                  <select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-product-template product-form__input" id="SingleOptionSelector-0" data-index="option1">
                    
    '.$row1["size_s"].'
 '.$row1["size_m"].'
 '.$row1["size_l"].'
 '.$row1["size_xl"].'
 '.$row1["size_36"].'
 '.$row1["size_37"].'
 '.$row1["size_38"].'
 '.$row1["size_39"].'
 '.$row1["size_40"].'
 '.$row1["size_41"].'
 '.$row1["size_42"].'
 '.$row1["size_43"].'
 '.$row1["size_44"].'
 '.$row1["size_45"].'
                    
                  </select>
                </div>
              
            </select>

            
              



          </form>
    <br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn--small-wide" id="add-cart-view" value="В корзину"  data-id="'.$row1["products_id"].'" > 

        </div><br></div>

     <div class="small--hide product-single__meta">

        <h1 itemprop="name" class="product-single__title">'.$row1["title"].'</h1>

        

        <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
          <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">

          <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">

          <p class="product-single__price product-single__price-product-template">
            
              <span class="visually-hidden">Regular price</span>
              <s id="ComparePrice-product-template" class="hide"></s>
              <span class="product-price__price product-price__price-product-template">
                <span id="ProductPrice-product-template"
                  itemprop="price" content="30.0">
                  '.group_numerals($row1["price"]).' грн
                </span>
                <span class="product-price__sale-label product-price__sale-label-product-template hide">Sale</span>
              </span>
            
          </p>
          <div class="">
          <p>Описание товара</p>
    Просто лучший свитшот!</div>
          <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="product-form product-form-product-template" data-section="product-template">
            
              
                <div class="selector-wrapper js product-form__item">
                  <label for="SingleOptionSelector-0">
                    <br>Размер
                  </label>
                  <select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-product-template product-form__input" id="SingleOptionSelector-0" data-index="option1">
                    
    '.$row1["size_s"].'
 '.$row1["size_m"].'
 '.$row1["size_l"].'
 '.$row1["size_xl"].'
 '.$row1["size_36"].'
 '.$row1["size_37"].'
 '.$row1["size_38"].'
 '.$row1["size_39"].'
 '.$row1["size_40"].'
 '.$row1["size_41"].'
 '.$row1["size_42"].'
 '.$row1["size_43"].'
 '.$row1["size_44"].'
 '.$row1["size_45"].'
                    
                  </select>
                </div>
              
            </select>

            
              



          </form>
    <br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn--small-wide" id="add-cart-view" value="В корзину"  data-id="'.$row1["products_id"].'" > 

        </div>
  
   </div>

';

   
}
 while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1));


 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uploads_images WHERE products_id='$id'",$link);
If (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo '
<br>
<p>Доп. фото</p>

';
do
{
    
$img_path = './uploads_images/'.$row["image"];
$max_width = 70; 
$max_height = 70; 
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_path); 
$ratioh = $max_height/$height; 
$ratiow = $max_width/$width; 
$ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow); 

$width = intval($ratio*$width); 
$height = intval($ratio*$height);    
    
    
echo '
<div class="small--hide thumbnails-wrapper">
<div id="block-img-slide">
  
<li class="grid__item medium-up--one-quarter product-single__thumbnails-item">

<a href="#image'.$row["id"].'"><img src="'.$img_path.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" /></a>

</li>
</div> 
</div>


<div class="site-header__menu thumbnails-wrapper">
<div id="block-img-slide2">
  
<li class="grid__item medium-up--one-quarter product-single__thumbnails-item">

<a href="#image'.$row["id"].'"><img src="'.$img_path.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" /></a>

</li>
</div> 
</div>

';
}
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));

}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE products_id='$id' AND visible='1'",$link);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$query_reviews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_reviews WHERE products_id='$id' AND moderat='1' ORDER BY reviews_id DESC",$link);

If (mysql_num_rows($query_reviews) > 0)
{
$row_reviews = mysql_fetch_array($query_reviews);
do
{

        
}
 while ($row_reviews = mysql_fetch_array($query_reviews));
}
else
{

} 


}
 
?>
</div>
```

Стили (сюда не вместилось)

[ТЫК](http://185.185.69.207/css/style.css)

Comment: Пожалуйста добавьте код вашего сайта

Comment: @Denisoed добавил!

Comment: Тяжело понять код, напутано и нет, таблицы стилей. В общем у вас я почти уверен, что вы уменьшаете `margin-top` у каждой единицы товара, а именно картинки. Вы должны поднять весь блок который его объединяет, а не каждой единицы. Если я правильно понял код то мы говорим о `block-img-slide` попробуйте у него менять `margin`

Comment: Не нужно вставлять весь сайт, вставьте только блок с которым у вас проблемы.  HTML CSS код блока через  "фрагмент кода"

Comment: смотрите для помощи раздел как создать [mcve]  и [Что такое сниппеты?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4619/191482)